# Custom Installer with Wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm still very new to Wix so i'm trying to get my head around how it works. There is a lot to it and its a bit hard to get an understanding of it. If my Wix MSI Contains a bunch of patch files. Can i use a Custom Action with extract the files to a temp location, run a patcher, update the version with the patched file version and then run any other MSI actions?

I'm not really sure how to do this in the XML. I Assume there is some sort of execution sequence

Also if this is possible i need a way to dynamically add the patch files to the MSI during the Build. Can you base this on an output folder?

Answer (score -1):

WiX is far better than installshield and the like, but without seeing your existing .wixproj this is hard to answer directly. You can use custom actions to do all of what you want, but it's not exactly the "WiX way", as that would not be easily reversible for a rollback or uninstall. Dynamically adding files during a build is absolutely possible. I must absolutely direct you to Ramirez' WiX: A Developer's Guide for Windows Installer XML. I got stuck building a complicated installer like this, and this book was invaluable.

What I can easily say is that for the patching portion, you can run exec tasks to run the patcher program and pass the patch files you want to run. You can dump all of these to a temporary directory to do it.

Comment: Thanks, well at the moment my wix project is an empty shell. I can see that you can create a Custom Action which should be able to run my patcher. I was going to build in Rollback into the Patcher. Can wix call a custom rollback action?

Comment: Actually it's not the "Windows Installer" way which also means it's not the "InstallShield" way either.  WiX isn't magically better then InstallShield.  It's just a different way to author Windows Installer and they both have their pros and cons.  I speak from 16 years of InstallShield, 10 years of Windows Installer and 6 years of WiX experience.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you Christopher. Your posts have helped me a ton the last time I built an installer! My biggest concerns were that an outside patcher program is not likely to be easily reversible if they were to fail. If someone is trying to learn how everything works in WiX, the book I recommended I personally found highly invaluable. I have zero relation to the author, and I have given the exact same book to colleagues when they needed to learn the intricacies of WiX.

Comment: Yes, Ryan, you can call custom actions during rollback in WiX.

Comment: I agree with you Nick.  It's also very difficult to explain to someone who hasn't been in the installer trenches why what they are thinking about doing is a horrible idea.  Also nothing against the book as I I've plugged it in the past. http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2010/10/new-bookebook-available-wix-developers.html